# Is AWS Fargate EKS Container to Container communication encrypted at the network level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I see that ephemeral drives are now encrypted but is network communications between containers encrypted, say for HIPAA compliance. Looking specifically at Serverless Fargate with Kubernetes pods. A google of "fargate kubernetes network encryption" did not seem return relevant results, it was all about the ephemeral drives. If it is not, is there a way to do it?

Update:

I just [found something](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=971827&#971827) that said you can set up a [CNI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-custom-network.html) but it wasn't 100% clear to me that that's possible with Fargate EKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container to Container traffic is not encrypted by default in AWS ECS, Fargate or AWS EKS. Typically an add-on called a *service mesh* is responsible for this part of a cluster. The most famous *service mesh* implementation is [Istio](https://istio.io/) but Amazon has its manages service [AWS App Mesh](https://aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/).

That said, a *service mesh* is an abstract name that does not mean much, so not all *service mesh* implementation does have support for *encrypted traffic*.

*I don't have extensive experience with AWS Fargate.* But it looks like [AWS App Mesh support Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-app-mesh-with-fargate/) and AWS App Mesh have support for [Transport Layer Security](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/tls.html) and in *preview channel* also [mutual TLS authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/mutual-tls.html) and this is both *encrypted traffic* with *authentication* and you can typically configure *authorization* as well (e.g. what app is allowed to communicate with what app).

Answer (score 0):

AWS communications are generally not encrypted at the network level. I have a vague recollection there are a few exception for sound multi-region services. My understanding is container traffic is not encrypted at the network level.

The easiest option is usually application level encryption, but perhaps you need a VPN on each container? That's a bit of an overhead.

I believe many AWS services are PCI / HIPPA compliant. [This page](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/services-in-scope/) outlines compliance by service. ECS and EKS are currently HIPPA compliant but VPC is not, but VPC is PCI compliant for example.

Comment: I just [found something](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=971827&#971827) that said you can set up a CNI but it wasn't 100% clear to me that that's possible with Fargate EKS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-custom-network.html any chance you know more? I've not actually used fargate.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about K8s, no idea what CNI is. I use Fargate ECS which works fine, encrypted disk but not encrypted networking.